# SwiftUI VideoPlayer autoplay without leaking AVPlayer

Tags: swiftui, avkit

Presenting a `VideoPlayer` in a sheet

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showVideo) {
   VideoPlayerView(videoURL: postVideo.videoURL)
}
```

To get the video to autoplay, I've implemented the following view

```
struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    private var player: AVPlayer
    
    init(videoURL: URL) {
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .onAppear {
                player.play()
            }
            .onDisappear() {
                player.pause()
            }
    }
}
```

However, checking the Memory Graph, the `AVPlayer` is being leaking. Omitting the `onDisappear()` `player.pause()` line, the video's sound keeps playing even after dismissing the sheet.

Going with the simpler version that doesn't keep an instance of `AVPlayer` doesn't have those issues, but then I lose autoplay.

```
struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    let videoURL: URL
    
    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: videoURL))
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

What would be the correct way of achieving autoplay and not leaking?

(Not looking for UIViewRepresentable solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't init objects in `body` because `View` structs are just values with no lifetime so any objects you init will just get lost. Instead, your objects need to be init in actions like `.onAppear`, `.onChange` etc. and stored inside a property wrapper like `@State` - which essentially is another object that is given to the same `View` every time it is re-init, which you can do as follows:

```
struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    @State var player: AVPlayer? // the same value is given to the VideoPlayerView every time it is init
    let url: URL

  var body: some View {
      Group {
        if let player {
            VideoPlayer(player: player)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .onAppear {
                player.play()
            }
            .onDisappear() {
                player.pause()
            }
        }
        else {
            Text("Invalid") // usually onChange will only occur the first time if there is something can can appear so this is just a placeholder but you can try without this.
        }
      }
      .onChange(of: url, initial: true) { // fyi initial means on every appear
          if player?.url != url {
              player = AVPlayer(url: url) // setting this state causes body to be called and a new VideoPlayer to be init with this new player
          }  
      }
```

In case you're wondering how on earth does SwiftUI know which `View` to give each `@State` value back to - it uses it's path in the `View` hierarchy to identify it, so you have to take care not to move it to a different line in `body`. The `.id` modifier can be used to override the automatic path id.